# Linking cells in same Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, how can I set up a spreadsheet so when I type in one cell it will populate another cell in the same spreadsheet?

Comment: does this have to work in both directions, or will you always be updating one cell and not the other?

Answer (score 4):

I'll field this one.

If you want the contents of, say, C1 to mirror the contents of cell A1, you just need to set the formula in C1 to `=A1`.  From this point forward, anything you type in A1 will show up in C1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest way is to have a formula in Z99 =B4 so that when you type in B4 Excel will copy the value to Z99.

But maybe thats not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the example of Ben Hoffstein between two spreadsheets (cell from Sheet1 to Sheet2) you should use the formula =Sheet1!A1

Answer (score 0):

=Value(Click on cell you want to match assuming it's a number)

Copy, Paste Formula along column or row or array