# referencing the items in spreadsheet between different sheets

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am working with 2 sheets in a single spreadsheet and I want to link the items of cells of first sheet to the cells of second sheet so that when I make any change in a cell in one of the sheets the same change should take place in another sheet in its linked cell.

I followed what is being suggested here [Linking cells in same Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257794/linking-cells-in-same-excel-spreadsheet) but it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sheet you are making changes to is Sheet2, in sheet1 just use something like =Sheet2!A1 and the cell will directly show whatever is in the cell A1 in sheet2, etc.

If both sheets need hard coded values then you'll need to do something more complicated, like an event in VBA.

Comment: When I do this it would ask as #NAME? Then what should I do? Thank you

Comment: Maybe sheet is a different name. Go to A1 in sheet1 and type An equal sign then in the middle of typing go and click sheet2 then A1 and hit enter. That makes the link.